# Problem adding a module and namespace to same TS declaration file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

for some reason as soon as I add the module declaration, it breaks the previous JSX namespace code

**my.d.ts**

```
declare namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicAttributes {
        store?: any;
    }
}

import { AriaAttributes, DOMAttributes } from 'react';

declare module 'react' {
    interface HTMLAttributes<T> extends AriaAttributes, DOMAttributes<T> {
        details?: string;
    }
}
```

So at first everything was fine when I just had the `declare namespace JSX` code.  I added that because my tests were sending in a `store` prop to React/Redux and it didn't see store as a prop.

But after I added the **module** for another issue with my tests where I needed to account for a details prop, then it breaks my previous code that defined store and the test that was working fine after I defined that store prop is now breaking saying store again is not defined.

Am I supposed to combine this stuff in one file in a certain way here?  What's breaking the statements here?

Comment: I guess I had to add another .d.ts file and separate these statements out..then it worked...hmm

Comment: wrap it and it will work; `declare global { namespace JSX { interface IntrinsicAttributes { store; } } }`